# Set the value of JavaScript variable into a PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I want to set the value of a JavaScript variable into a PHP variable. How can that be done?

Kindly give me some suggestions.

## My code is :

```
document.getElementById("dummy").value=  <?php echo ("document.getElementById('txtplan').value"); ?> //document.formn.txtplan.options[document.formn.txt'+fld+'.selectedIndex].value //eval(''); $_POST['txtplan']
    alert(document.getElementById("dummy").value);  


<?php
    $planname = $_POST["dummy"];
    $plandetails = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM membershipplan where planname='$planname'");
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($plandetails))
    {?>
    document.getElementById("txtduration").value=<?php echo $row1['planduration']; ?>
    document.getElementById("txtplancontact").value=<?php echo $row1['plannoofcontacts']; ?>
    document.getElementById("txtplanamount").value=<?php echo $row1['planamount']; ?>

    <?php
    }
?>

});
```

am not do with this means kindly give me the alternative way for the above process

Comment: PHP is server-side, JS is client-side

Comment: i dont think that this is possible. Better find some other way to do this.

Comment: You can post it from a form, put it in the URL (GET-method) or you can use AJAX

Comment: in your code you are messing javascript and php which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
JS -> PHP = impossible (only if you send that info to PHP using POST or GET)  
PHP -> JS = possible   var text = <?php echo( $text ); ?> ;
```

The only reason for that is that the PHP code is executed on your server.

Answer (score 1):

**You cant do that** i.e you cant assign a javascript variable to a php variable
(**unless you are using cookie or ajax**) but u can assign a php variable to a javascript variable using

```
var a=<?php echo $a ?> ;
```

but be careful with that as the php variables will be executed in the server.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple. Impossible. Because,

- Java script is a client side scripting. Client machine can handle
  this script, If it is possible to assign javascript value to PHP
  variable that leads to some sort of **vulnerability**.
- So this can't be done.

If you want to accomplish something by doing this kind of assignment, Definitly there would be a way of doing it. Post another question what do you want to do, you will be showered with answers.